# Getting Multiple Tuples

Tags: apache-spark

I have Tuples which look like this

([1, 2, 4],3,userdn1)
([1, 6, 7],1,userdn1)
([1, 2, 7],2,userdn1)

I'm  using an RDD to get the  tuples with the max count out of this which is the first tuple, but it's possible that I may have multiple tuples which may have the same count, How can I get multiple tuples which have the same max value ? Right now the max method only returns a single tuple

Comment: You can sort, take the first n elements, then the throw away the smaller values.

Comment: How would I know how many elements to take ?

Comment: If you don't know how many to take, then take the first one, then filter the RDD for item with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to get results like this?

```
//just try to initial some similar records
val rdd = sc.parallelize[(Array[Int],Int, String)](Array[(Array[Int],Int, String)]((Array(1,4), 3, "dn1"),(Array(1,2,4), 3, "dn1"),(Array(1,6,7), 1, "dn1"),(Array(1,2,7), 2, "dn1")))
//here max records you wanna
val max = rdd.map(t => t._1.length).max
val rddmax = rdd.filter(t => t._1.length == max)
```

here is the result:

```
rddmax.collect
res1: Array[(Array[Int], Int, String)] = Array((Array(1, 2, 4),3,dn1), (Array(1, 6, 7),1,dn1), (Array(1, 2, 7),2,dn1))
```